# .Htaccess remove all .php, paramater and add slash in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file which helps me to rewrite the http://domain/profile.php?uid=1 as http://domain/1

```
RewriteEngine on
#this removes .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /profile?uid=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

But when i add slash on the url, it gives me errors
also how can i add another parameter
for example:

http://domain/profile.php?uid=1&section=about

to

http://domain/1/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on
#remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
#rewrite /1/about
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ /profile?uid=$1&section=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: What url is giving you 404?